# Using const char* in a STXXL map

Tags: c++, stxxl

I've looked for it but I've not been able to find a solution. Sorry it this has been already posted.

I have to create a stxxl::map structure mapping const char* into const char* (the optimum would be string into string but I am aware stxxl containers don't accept non POD)

I have a problem defining the comp_type structure for const char*. Has anybody an example of that?

Here's the one that I wrote:

```
struct comp_type : public std::less<const char*>
{
        static int max_value()
        {
                return (std::numeric_limits<char>::max)();
        }
};
```

Comment: Change `static int max_value()` to `bool operator ()(char const* const) const`, return a `bool` instead of an `int`, and don't inherit from `std::less<>`. And -1 for not investigating how comparison functors for the standard library work in general -- many sites explain this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet. So I am posting a reply.

@ildjarn: With `stxxl` you need `static T min_value()` and `static T max_value()` in certain cases.

@Fabrizio: Are you sure you want to compare two `const char*`s directly? Which is what you are doing by inheriting from `std::less<const char*>`. If your intention is to compare two strings you'll need something like this,

```
struct comp_type : public std::binary_function<const char*, const char*, bool>
{
    bool operator ()(const char* left, const char* right)
    {
        return strcmp(left, right) < 0;
    }

    static const char* min_value() { return "\0"; } // I hope this is the minimum

    static const char* max_value() {...} // I don't know of any maximum value
};
```

Note that it is `static const char* max_value()` and not `static int max_value()`. Hope this helps.